# Will the Xcode archive I submitted to Apple be okay if Generic iOS Device wasn't used to create the archive?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I guess the title says it all.

Basically, I'm new to Xcode and late last night I submitted an app to Apple. Everything went okay (creating the archive, validation, uploading) but this morning I noticed that Xcode was still connected to a physical iPhone and that's what was selected in the Device list. I'm now thinking that when I created the archive last night I probably did't select Generic iOS Device.

Will this matter? And, if so, how? Do I need to reject this binary and upload a newly created archive?

If this has already been answered elsewhere, feel free to refer me to that - I did do a search but didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is clearly mentioned that you can select `Generic iOS Device` or `your device name`.

And so **it doesn't matter**.

From [Apple's Developer Site](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devf37a1db04)

> **To create an archive**
>
> In the Xcode project editor, choose a generic device—Generic iOS Device, Generic tvOS Device, or *Generic iOS Device* + watchOS Device—*or your device name* from the Scheme toolbar menu.
>
> You can’t create an archive of a simulator build. If a device is connected to your Mac, the device name appears in the Scheme toolbar menu. When you disconnect the device, the menu item changes to the generic device name.

Comment: @user3741598 I have linked the document on top. As for the review, I think that part is not related to what device you select while creating the archive.

Comment: what's the reason for the distinction then?

Comment: The other items (simulator/devices) can be selected for running the build.
Only for creating an archive, we can select anyone (as they have to support every device on App Store anyway)
@bze12

Answer (score 3):

it's ok :)

we can create archive if we select Genric ios device or when we connect with physical iPhone .

so both are same.

you can not create archive if you not select genric ios device or iphone device you connect with xcode. archive option will show disable.